# Using private docker registry with Helm in Kubernetes error

Tags: kubernetes

this is probably fairly simple, but I'm kind of lost here so any help would be appreciated.

I followed the instructions to set up a private docker registry over here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

The instructions worked, and the following deployment of a pod worked from the repo:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: esrhost/node-hello
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Now, when I try to replicate this in a Helm chart, I'm getting the following error:

```
me@me:~/projects/helm-test/init-test$ helm install --name node-hello . --set service.type=NodePort
Error: release node-hello failed: Deployment in version "v1beta2" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1beta2.Deployment: Spec: v1beta2.DeploymentSpec: Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec: Spec: v1.PodSpec: ImagePullSecrets: []v1.LocalObjectReference: readObjectStart: expect { or n, parsing 696 ...ecrets":["... at {"apiVersion":"apps/v1beta2","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"labels":{"app":"init-test","chart":"init-test-0.1.0","heritage":"Tiller","release":"node-hello"},"name":"node-hello-init-test","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"init-test","release":"node-hello"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"init-test","release":"node-hello"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"esrhost/node-hello:stable","imagePullPolicy":null,"livenessProbe":{"httpGet":{"path":"/","port":"http"}},"name":"init-test","ports":[{"containerPort":8080,"name":"http","protocol":"TCP"}],"readinessProbe":{"httpGet":{"path":"/","port":"http"}},"resources":null}],"imagePullSecrets":["regcred {}"]}}}}
```

The issue is definitely with imagePullSecrets.

My values.yaml is the following:

```
 replicaCount: 1

 image:
   repository: esrhost/node-hello
   tag: stable
   pullpolicy: ifnotpresent
   # .Values.image.repoSecret
   repoSecret: regcred

 service:
   type: ClusterIP
   port: 8080

 ingress:
   enabled: false
   annotations: {}
     # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
   path: /
   hosts:
     - chart-example.local
   tls: []
   #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
   #    hosts:
   #      - chart-example.local

 resources: {}

 nodeSelector: {}

 tolerations: []

 affinity: {}
```

Basically the only non-default thing I have is my repository, and the repoSecret variable which I'm using in the following template deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "init-test.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "init-test.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "init-test.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "init-test.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "init-test.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - {{ .Values.image.repoSecret }}
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
    {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

As you can see I've added spec->template->spec->imagePullSecrets and assigned the .Values.image.repoSecret variable.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this error. As far as I'm aware secrets are being propagated from deployments to pods, so it shouldn't make a difference that I've assigned it there.

TL;DR - Added a docker registry to K8s - works with kubectl. Added the same to a default nginx Helm chart - doesn't work. Confuse.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you use Kubernetes cluster version 1.9.* or even higher.

Therefore, you have to edit your `deployment.yaml` file and replace `apiVersion: apps/v1beta2` with `apiVersion: apps/v1`, as old `apiVersion` had been deprecated starting from Kubernetes v1.9.0 according to the versions [ChangeLog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

You can check supported `api-versions` within your Kubernetes cluster using the next command:

```
kubectl api-versions
```

There was a similar issue discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55894).